# How to get the correct and clean path while doing drag and drop in C#?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I am developing a small application which takes in a csv file, removes all rows except those which have "critical" in their second column. You simply type in the input path and the output path and the manipulation is done. All was fine until I decided to do it as drag and drop. I drag the input file into the Windows Form, and the textbox automatically fills with the path I need. Great. Then I fill the output path. However, when I press the execute button, I get "illegal character in path" error. But when I type the same exact path that came up upon dragging, the program works! Any idea if their is something like a hidden character I cannot see? Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.AllowDrop = true;

    }



    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String inputpath = textBox1.Text;

        String outputpath = textBox2.Text;  

        MessageBox.Show(inputpath, outputpath);





        var retainedLines = File.ReadAllLines(@inputpath)


            .Where((x, i) => i == 0 || (x.Split(',')[1]).Contains("critical")); 
        if (inputpath.Equals(outputpath))
        {
        File.Delete(@inputpath);
        }            
        File.WriteAllLines(@outputpath, retainedLines);

    }

    private void Form1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] fileList = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);

        foreach (string s in fileList)
        {

            String k= String.Format("{0}{1}", s, Environment.NewLine);
            k = k.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
            textBox1.Clear();
            textBox1.Text = k;

        }




    }


    private void Form1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, false))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;


    }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is in these two lines

```
 String k= String.Format("{0}{1}", s, Environment.NewLine);
 k = k.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
```

Here you add [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (that Windows OS defines as a couple of chars `\r\n`) and then the code removes the `\n` but leaves the `\r`.

So when you try to read that file name you get an invalid character in path.

A simple workaround is

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String inputpath = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    ....
}
```

but probably you need to revise a bit how do you add the files in the TextBox1.
For example, your code ignore if the Drop operation has more than one file, just the last one in the list is used. (If this is intentional then disregard this note)

The `\r` character is just the escaped representation in C# (and other C derived languages) of the CARRIAGE RETURN char  (CR U+000D)

For more details about the Carriage Return And Line Feed characters see [this article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

Comment: WORKED LIKE A CHARM! Thanks a lot! Could you please enlighten me about the \r character?